# Substitute column values of a dataframe with the corresponding items in an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe which contains an array of numbers from 1 to 5 and I have an array containing five words. I would like to find the simplest, most compact and most elegant way in Python to **"in place"** replace the numbers in the column with the corresponding words. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# This is the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'color': [4, 1, 2, 5, 1]})

#   code   color 
# 0    A       4 
# 1    B       1 
# 2    C       2 
# 3    D       5 
# 4    E       1

# This is the array
colors = ["blue", "yellow", "red", "white", "black"] 

# This is what I wish to obtain
#   code   color 
# 0    A   white 
# 1    B    blue 
# 2    C  yellow 
# 3    D   black 
# 4    E    blue
```

I am certain that the numbers in columns "color" are not NaN or outside range [1,5].
No check is necessary. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should do**

```
df['color'] = df['color'].apply(lambda c: colors[c-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create helper `dictionary` by `enumerate` and mapping values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), if no match is created missing values `NaN`:

```
df['color'] = df['color'].map(dict(enumerate(colors, 1)))
print (df)
  code   color
0    A   white
1    B    blue
2    C  yellow
3    D   black
4    E    blue
```